# Apache Flink side-output not outputing exected results when order of processors swapped in the original stream

Tags: apache-flink

I have a small Flink app:

```java
public class App {
  public static final OutputTag<String> numberOutputTag = new OutputTag<String>("side-output") {
  };

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    DataStreamSource<String> text = env.fromElements(
      "abc,123"
    );

    // Router will split input on commas and redirect number strings to the side output
    SingleOutputStreamOperator<String> ingestStream = text
      .process(new RouterProcessor())
      .process(new UppercaseProcessor())
      ;

    DataStream<String> numberStream = ingestStream.getSideOutput(numberOutputTag)
      // Prepends a "$" to the values.
      .map(new MoneyMapper());

    numberStream.print();
    ingestStream.print();

    env.execute();
  }
}
```

```java
class RouterProcessor extends ProcessFunction<String, String> {
  @Override
  public void processElement(String value, Context ctx, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
    String[] tokens = value.split(",");

    for (String token : tokens) {
      if (token.matches("[0-9]+")) {
        ctx.output(App.numberOutputTag, token);
      } else {
        out.collect(token);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```java
class MoneyMapper implements MapFunction<String, String> {
  @Override
  public String map(String t) throws Exception {
    return "$" + t;
  }
}
```

```java
class UppercaseProcessor extends ProcessFunction<String, String> {
  @Override
  public void processElement(String value, Context ctx, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
    out.collect(value.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

I'd expect it to output something similar to:

```
18> ABC
18> $123
```

However, it only outputs:

```
10> ABC
```

If I swap the order of the processors to:

```java
.process(new UppercaseProcessor())
.process(new RouterProcessor())
```

everything works as expected.

I've read the documentation but I don't see anything that would explain why this is as it is. I'm curious if I'm missing something or doing something wrong.

I've included a GitHub jist here for easier viewing with all the supporting files: https://gist.github.com/baelec/95f41d875dda0a2806a0fb9b9313b90e

Here is a repo if you'd prefer to download the sample project: https://github.com/baelec/flink_sample_broken_0

EDIT: I see that StackOverflow asks us to avoid comments like "Thanks!" but I don't have enough rep to visibly upvote the responses so thanks David and Jaya for your help. I had made some incorrect assumptions regarding side outputs. I appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`numberOutputTag` side output emit logic happens inside `RouterProcessor`. So you need to extract the side output from the SingleOutputStreamOperator returned by the `RouterProcessor` process function. But in your code, your side output logic extraction happens after the `UppercaseProcessor` function.

Change something like below,

```
SingleOutputStreamOperator<String> tempStream = text.process(new RouterProcessor());
SingleOutputStreamOperator<String> ingestStream = tempStream.process(new UppercaseProcessor());

DataStream<String> numberStream = tempStream.getSideOutput(numberOutputTag).map(new MoneyMapper());

numberStream.print();
ingestStream.print();
```

Note: Check the usage of tempStream variable in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are taking the side output from the `UppercaseProcessor`, which doesn't use a side output.

It's easier to see what's wrong if you look at the job graph, which looks like this:

[image]

If you rearrange the code to be like this:

```java
SingleOutputStreamOperator<String> ingestStream = text
  .process(new RouterProcessor());

DataStream<String> numberStream = ingestStream.getSideOutput(numberOutputTag)
  .map(new MoneyMapper());

numberStream.print();

ingestStream
  .process(new UppercaseProcessor())
  .print();
```

then it works as you expected, and the job graph has become this:

[image]